# Can I allow drawable files to contain capital letters? if not...?

Tags: android, resources, drawable, rename

I am currently developing an Android version of a pre-existing iOS application.

I have the original resource folder with all the drawable files (200+ .png files).

The person who wrote the iOS named every single .png file like this: "examplePngName.png"

is there anyway I can allow the res drawable folders to allow capitals or a better way than manually renaming over 200 files..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the web and download a `Bulk Rename Utility` for your OS.
For example [BulkRenameUtility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) (Note: this one purports to handle case changes as you require, but I haven't tried it myself. It was just the first one on the list in a quick google search!).

Comment: Yeah I just got a file rename program.